# Nilpotent of subgroup implies nilpotent of group

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, quotient-group, nilpotent-groups

Suppose that I have two normal subgroups $L, M$ in $H$ such that $L<M$ and $M / L$ is nilpotent of class $2$.

Suppose also that $[H,[H,H]]$ is contained in $[M,M]$.

Can I then conclude that $H / L$ is nilpotent? To be fair, I have no idea of how to prove it but I have never worked with nilpotent groups to have a counterexample neither.

I just know how to see that $H / L$ is nilpotent-by-nilpotent, since we have a short exact sequence $$1\to [H,[H,H]]L/ L \to H/L \to H/ [H,[H,H]]L \to 1,$$ but I do not know if the property $[H,[H,H]] < [M,M]$ gives us more information about $H/L$.

Thank you!

Comment: @verret I don't see that. The smallest non-nilpotent group is $S_3$, which has no nilpotent sections of class$2$. On the other hand "$M/L$ is nilpotent of class $2$, that is $[M,[M,M]$ is contained in $H$" makes no sense, so I am not sure that I undersatnd the question.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I mean that it is contained in $L$, just the definition of nilpotency... Sorry

Comment: In fact $L$ is not really relevant to the question, and we might as well assume that $L=1$. I am still thinking about it!

Comment: @DerekHolt The OP says "nilpotent of class 2", but then also says $[M,[M,M]]$ contained in $L$, which is equivalent to "nilpotent of class at most 2". So there really are two different questions here and I assumed the OP meant the second one. I guess OP should clarify. But now I see that the next condition is not satisfied.

Comment: @verret I explicitely want the nilpotency to be $2$, not at most $2$... sorry for the confusion, you are right with the counterexample otherwise.

Comment: Wait. Changing all your letters to make it easier for me ($H$ becomes $G$ and $M$ becomes $N$), and quotienting out by $L$, don't you have a normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ such that $N$ is nilpotent, and $G/N'$ is also nilpotent? Then $G$ is nilpotent by a result of Philip Hall.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks so much! I didn't know about that result!